# How to store multiple user IDs for each "event" ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm totally new to MySQL. 
I'm working on a university courses system where each course ("event") has many students("users") that are signed in to that course.

I want a to build a MySQL table that for each course ID will store all the students IDs that are signed in to it. I found two approaches:

1. Serialize students IDs (using json for example)
2. Create a new row for every new student with course ID and student ID

The first approach has a performance issue because of serialization/de-serialization of students IDs, and the second approach will cause the table to explode very quickly.

What do you think I should do? Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a third table that will store students opted courses. The table comprises with three columns. First will be id (primary key), second will be course_id (foreign key to course_table) and third one will be student_id (foreign key to users table ). You could also add timestamp column as well.

Comment: @ranjeetsingh what does the id do (this is a trick question)

Comment: Id is a primary key (auto-incremental and unique number). If you ever want to delete a row then you can easily delete by using id easily if you have that id in delete button or you can easily sort by asc and desc by using id as it is fast way to do it. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case is a `Many-to-Many` mapping.

You would have 3 tables.

1. User
2. Events
3. User_Events

The third table will store the mappings, it should consist of two columns, `user_id` and `event_id`

`user_id` would be the foreign key for the `User` table, similarly, `event_id` would be the foreign key for the `Event` table. You can then retrieve data by Joins in queries.

so if you have users with ID 1, 2, and 3

and similarly  courses with ID 1, 2, 3, 4

Here's how you will represent students that are signed in a course.

```
user_id, event_id
  1         2
  1         3
  2         1
  3         4
```

This means, user 1 is signed in course 2 and 3, user 2 in course 1 and user with ID 3 in course with ID 4.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what you suggesting is similar to the second option I described. I'm afraid that the User_Events table will be very large and it will effect performance. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Each student/user can be in several courses/events.

Each course/event can contain several students/users.

So you need a bridge table containing all relations:

- user_event (userid, eventid)

with a unique constraint on userid + eventid.

(You can add a technical ID (e.g. user_event_id) to the table, but that's not necessary.)